# How to fix SSS glitch when surfaces of same object clip (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, subsurface-scattering

For quite a while now I noticed that I get those very shiny lines whenever surfaces clip through each other. The only ways I know for now is post-process or in edit mode move vertexes just enough to make surfaces be near each other instead of clipping through.

I know it is caused by SSS (both SSS and Principled SSS give that result).

The question is. Can I get this fixed by some trick with nodes instead of spending hours to cover that up?

[image: Example of what I mean]